# how to create one div as fixed and second scrollable?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am new to UI,
creating one blog layout in HTML with Bootstrap4, I am following this layout...'removed', how to create first div fixed and second scroll-able and then one full width banner and so on.

Comment: This will be  done by using html, CSS & javascript/jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="w-100 bg-dark" style="height: 50px;">
    </div>
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-6 bg-primary" style="height: 50vh;">
            <div class="position-fixed bg-danger">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-secondary " style="height: 100vh;">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

don't forget to put height and width
///
Other and I think better way :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <aside class="col-2 px-0 fixed-top bg-danger">

    </aside>

    <main class="col offset-2 h-100">

    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks sir, I was looking for this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp, your codes helped too, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Before posting a question here, you need to try something from your end then if you are stuck, you can post questions here to get an answer.

First Step:
You need to learn the basics of HTML & CSS. (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp)

To make a section FIXED, you need to use the POSITION property in CSS. (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

I guess these are enough for you to get started.
Happy learning!